# -bash export message when opening terminal on mac

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

I'm having the following message whenever I open my terminal on mac OS Mojave:

Last login: Sun Sep 22 20:35:33 on ttys000
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export:`/Users/MYNAME/.local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/MYNAME/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin': not a valid identifier

How do I get rid of it?